# Image inside another image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiimageview, z-index

I'm based on this code:[Custom MKAnnotationView with frame,icon and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520274/custom-mkannotationview-with-frame-icon-and-image)

And I'm trying to do it a little different...I have an image non-transparent, and I want put an image inside.
My problem is that the background image cover my image. So it looks something like: http://cl.ly/image/0E0S00072G1n

My code is so:

```
    annotationImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_fb"];

    UIImage *frame = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_fb"];
    ImagePin *imagePinImage = annotation;   

    NSString *urlStringForImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imagePinImage.image];
    NSURL *urlForImage = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringForImage];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlForImage]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-placeholder.png"]];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(annotationImageView.image.size.width, annotationImageView.image.size.height));
    [frame drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(2, 2, 48, 38)]; // the frame your inner image

    annotationImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Does z-indez exist in object-c? or how should I do??
Thanks.
**EDIT:** I tried also with:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(annotationImageView.image.size.width, annotationImageView.image.size.height), NO, 0);
```