# How to show Image over Map not as Pin but as seperate image?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimage, mapkit

I want to show two flags on Map but these are not pins. I search a lot for this but could not find solutions but to add as pin.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Map Overlay `MKOverlayView`.

Check these tutorials:

- [Overlay View](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial)
- [Image Overlay](http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/05/ios-maps-with-image-overlays/)

**Creating overlay**

- Creating a `MKOverlayView`

Create a subclass of `MKOverlayView` like:

**.h**
    #import 
    #import

```
@interface MapOverlayView : MKOverlayView
{
}
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "MapOverlayView.h"

@implementation MapOverlayView

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, theRect, imageReference); 
}

@end
```

- Adding Overlay

Implement the `viewForOverlay:` ,inside that create the overlay and add to map.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{

    MapOverlay *mapOverlay = (MapOverlay *)overlay;    
    MapOverlayView *mapOverlayView = [[[MapOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:mapOverlay] autorelease];

    return mapOverlayView;
}
```

Comment: I think MKAnnotationView is better suited for the use case

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `MKAnnotationView` with `image` property like bellow in `viewForAnnotation:` method..

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"Current";           
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
        return nil;

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"];
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;            
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: where to set the image location?

Comment: when you add any location with lat-long in your class at that time this delegate method called automatically and this image drop with that lat-log on that location ..

Comment: @NG_SE see demo example for custom pin on mkmapview from this link http://iphoneapp-dev.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-to-place-animated-annotations-on.html

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
annotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"try"];
    annotation.canShowCallout = YES;

    annotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];


    return annotation;
```

and do not use annotation.animatesDrop property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talkin about `MKMapView`:
To show an image instead of Pin annotation , you need to override MKMapView's method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

Like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation{
    static NSString* annotationIdentifier = @"Identifier";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    if(annotationView)
        return annotationView;
    else
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
// here you need to give the image you want instead of pin
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"balloon.png"]];        
            return annotationView;
        }
        return nil;
        }
```

Comment: How to set image location?

Comment: Refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520274/custom-mkannotationview-with-frame-icon-and-image